# Have a 2013 Nissan Murano 3.5l

Tags: engine

Changed oil  - read on line that 5qts is max, however, when adding all 5 quarts it seemed too much.  Then we decided to look at the manual, which says 4.78 quarts. Will this create a problem?   Should I drain and add to the OEM amount?

Answer (score 1):

I always add a bit less, then run the engine and allow to settle. Then check the level and top up as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I have a 2011 Murano and have been putting the whole 5 qt container for years.  I do it myself so I let let old oil drain for an hour +. And a new filter. When I found out many years ago the US manufacturers reduced the amount of oil needed for a change ( to reduce maintenance costs) by moving the marks on the dipstick - period-; I thought it is probably not rocket science.  But do NOT get the level so high there is any chance of touching the crank.